# Handler or Alarm Manager for writing to a file ever second

Tags: android

If  I want to write to a file every 1 second some infomation that I get from the phone (in addition to updating activity GUI), then would I be better using a recursive handler(postDelayed) or should I use alarmmanager?

Which one is more stable? Which one would you recommend? My worry with the handler that if one timeout crashes (or for some reason didn't get called) then none of the rest will start. With Alarm manager, I don't think you have this but "some people" say it is too heavy for 1 sec intervals and you don't have much control over gui (I find it hard to belive the later statement).

Please advise

Thank you

Comment: Using `AlarmManager` for one-second polls is like swatting a fly with a Buick. Doing disk I/O every second, rather than batching it up and doing it less frequently, is harsh on the battery. Also, bear in mind that your disk I/O needs to be done on a background thread, but your UI updates need to be done on the main application thread, which is further reason to batch up the I/O work.

Comment: @CommonsWare, so using handler with postDelayed is more recommended for this is better right? Good point about the batch I/O, I just don't want to lose data if something happened before writing the batch

Comment: Consider using an IntentService to do the suggested batch-thing.

Comment: I can use asyncTask to do the batch work. I am not familiar with services yet and when I looked it up, it seems it has learning curve and my deadline is very tight :(. So  Iam trying to avoid it as much as  I can